# nginx + php-fpm chdir not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, chroot, symlink

I'm meeting a problem with getting my nginx and php-fpm working.

I'm getting an error 504 when I try to access my application.

I have a structure like this;

```
data/mywebsite/
 |    
 |---revisions/
 |
 |---shared/
 |
 |---released/
       |---web/
       |---app/
       |---.../
```

in my fpm pool I have the following:

```
chroot = /data/mywebsite/
chdir = /released/web/
```

in my nginx:

```
root /data/mywebsite/released/web/;

fastcgi_param                  SCRIPT_FILENAME              /web/released$fastcgi_script_name;
```

So what I want is to chroot on `data/mywebsite/` and the application located in `data/mywebsite/released/web/` to access files in the folder shared.

nb: I don't know if it is worth mentioning but I have a soft link like this `released -> /data/mywebsite/revisions/...`

Comment: Have you mixed `/data/mybesite` and `/data/mywebsite` in the question?

Comment: Indeed i made a mistake in the question. It's "mywebsite" everywhere, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you plan to use PHP-FPM chroot, you need to copy quite a lot of system files inside the chroot for it to work properly.

For example, you need `/data/mybesite/dev`, `/data/mybesite/proc`, `/data/mybesite/sys` directories / pseudo-filesystems and files inside `/data/mybesite/lib` and many others.

You also cannot use symlinks that point outside the chroot.

If you are using `/data/mybesite` as the `chroot` directory, then a symlink in `/data/mybesite/example1/example2` that points to `/data/mybesite/example2` points to `/data/mybesite/data/mybesite/example2` directory when used inside the chroot.

My recommendation is not to use the `chroot` feature unless you are prepared to spend time learning the requirements for the chroot environment to run PHP-FPM applications inside it. I did this work for one project I worked on, and it took several days even when using a helper program for the job.